# Assign a symbolic tensor with determinant greater than zero in Mathematica

Tags: tensors

I can create a symbolic tensor in Mathematica:

```
$Assumptions = F \[Element] Arrays[{3, 3}, Reals]
```

Is there anyway that I can tell Mathematica, that the determinant of this **F** tensor is greater than zero, i.e. $|\boldsymbol{F}| > 0$ ?